# Prove : If $I=(p(x))$ is a prime ideal in $ F[x]$ then $p(x)$ is irreducible.my claim is F need not to be field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In this problem even if I relax the condition that $F$ is a field,then it still remains true, I guess, because if $p$ is reducible, then $p=fg$ where $f,g$ are both nonunit polynomials. Now $fg$ is in $(p)$ but none of $f$ and $g$ are in $(p)$ which contradicts that $(p)$ is prime.

Here the only requirement is that $F$ be an integral domain so that $f(x)$ and $p(x)$  can be associate.